# How to find all occurrences of $ which are not escaped or preceded by \ in java

Tags: java, regex

Test Cases :

1. he is having $money 500
2. he is having \$money 500
3. $
4. \$

Matches should be the 1st & 3rd one, since 2nd & 4th already contains escaped "$".

I tried - `Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(^\\\\$)");` but it doesn't match any. Please help.

Comment: Do you have to deal with `\\$` (2 ``\`` to escape ``\``)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Negative Lookbehind here to exclude the already escaped `$` characters.

```
(?<!\\\\)\\$
```

Comment: This is neither correct as regex string literal nor raw regex.

Comment: are you going to keep fixing it until it is the same as the other answer?

Comment: A string would have two backslashes in Java.

Comment: `(?<!\\\\)\\$` this works perfect for me (java), but why we need 4 `\\` ?

Comment: `matcher.replaceAll("\\$")` returns the same string with no escaping. Any idea what could be going wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<!\\)\$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/34

Comment: maybe start and end with .* so it matches the entire line, not just the $

Comment: @CharlieS OP just wants to match `$`.So it would be overkill to match to whole.

Comment: he wants to match 1 and 3, does he mean the lines or the $? i couldn't be sure so gave the extra.. doesn't matter since the OP has accepted an incorrect answer anyway :)

Comment: @CharlieS yeah let's RIP :P

Comment: and is still only really correct if you include the ""